# Class not found for inline method - what can cause that?

Tags: java, kotlin, jasync-sql

I am getting an error with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/jasync/sql/db/ConcreteConnectionBase$flatten$$inlined$mapTry$1
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.ConcreteConnectionBase.releaseIfNeeded(ConcreteConnectionBase.kt:98) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.mysql.MySQLConnection.sendPreparedStatementDirect(MySQLConnection.kt:299) [jasync-mysql-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.ConcreteConnectionBase$sendPreparedStatement$1.invoke(ConcreteConnectionBase.kt:75) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.ConcreteConnectionBase$sendPreparedStatement$1.invoke(ConcreteConnectionBase.kt:16) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.interceptor.ConnectionInterceptorHelperKt.wrapPreparedStatementWithInterceptors(ConnectionInterceptorHelper.kt:35) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.ConcreteConnectionBase.sendPreparedStatement(ConcreteConnectionBase.kt:67) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.pool.ConnectionFactory.test(ConnectionFactory.kt:81) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.pool.ConnectionFactory.test(ConnectionFactory.kt:14) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.pool.ObjectPoolActor.sendAvailableItemsToTest(ActorBasedObjectPool.kt:342) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.pool.ObjectPoolActor.handleTestAvailableItems(ActorBasedObjectPool.kt:282) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.pool.ObjectPoolActor.onReceive(ActorBasedObjectPool.kt:226) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at com.github.jasync.sql.db.pool.ActorBasedObjectPool$actor$1.invokeSuspend(ActorBasedObjectPool.kt:141) [jasync-common-0.9.41.jar:?]
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32) [kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar:1.3.10-release-253 (1.3.10)]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:233) [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:?]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594) [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:?]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60) [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:?]
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742) [kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.jasync.sql.db.ConcreteConnectionBase$flatten$$inlined$mapTry$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) [?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) [?:1.8.0_144]
    ... 17 more
```

You can see the source code for `ConcreteConnectionBase` class here:
https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql/blob/master/db-async-common/src/main/java/com/github/jasync/sql/db/ConcreteConnectionBase.kt

`flatMapTry` and `mapTry` are inlined functions. The weird thing is that the above stacktrace is not consistent (ie not happening on all instances).

I decompiled the jar but didn't see any evidence of missing classes (as far as I understood it).
Is there another cause I might be missing here?

Comment: if you have about 20 min and can read this post (https://jrebel.com/rebellabs/rebel-labs-tutorial-do-you-really-get-classloaders/) you may be able to detect what's happening there. Class loading issues are often hard to find.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but in this case, it is a class from the same file.

Comment: are you using proguard or something?

Comment: No, it's a server-side application, running on JRE 8.

Comment: Check you have the missing class in the `.jar` files of your app. Make sure all transitive dependencies are included. Check the versions of libraries (it might be the case some libraries were upgraded/downgraded while dependency resolution)

Comment: Thanks! it turned out to be that a `gradle clean` solve it. The artifact was corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the artifact was corrupted. `gradle clean` fixed the issue.

The way I found it is by using:

```
>jar tf jasync-common-0.9.24.jar  | grep ConcreteConnectionBase | grep mapTry
com/github/jasync/sql/db/ConcreteConnectionBase$flatten$$inlined$mapTry$1$lambda$1.class
com/github/jasync/sql/db/ConcreteConnectionBase$flatten$$inlined$mapTry$1.class
```

And comparing it with:

`>jar tf jasync-common-0.9.41.jar  | grep ConcreteConnectionBase | grep mapTry`

Which was empty.